# I accidentally made my laptop unbootable using dd

Tags: linux, ubuntu, boot, data-recovery, dd

### The story so far...

- I was experimenting with Unix's **dd** program on my **Ubuntu** laptop, trying to find a quick method to wipe a micro SD card securely.
- I set dd in motion, came back a few minutes later, and the whole system had crashed.
- When I try to reboot, I get a screen saying "checking media" and then a notification that the boot has failed.

### What I'd like to achieve...

- There's a modicum of data - a couple of GB - that I'd like to recover if at all possible.
- Also, I'd like to be able to use the laptop as before this calamity, but without deleting any data.

### More information

- I am able to boot from a USB, but, if I try to re-install Ubuntu, the only option it gives me is to wipe everything on disk at present.
- dd was only running for long enough to wipe, at most, 100 GB of a 1 TB disk. So there must be *some* recoverable data, right?

Comment: MicroSD cards are never called `/dev/sda` because they are not handled by the `sd` driver. `sda` is the first SATA or USB disk. You've wiped your disk.

Comment: Yes. You're quite right. Is there any hope for the data that was on the disk? As I said, insufficient time passed for all 1TB to be wiped. I was hoping it was just the system files. Is that possible? And, if so, how might I recover the data?

Comment: Please look at links at the top, under the _This question already has answers here_ header.